# Offline support of WebSite 

Tags: jakarta-ee, browser, offline

I am working on a WebSite which requires offline storage of data. i.e. if the network is down the data is stored locally on the client's PC ad it is sent to the server next time the user goes online.

For detecting the network status I have used jquery AJAX calls to the server (Couldnt find any thing better than that ? please suggest other possible ways) . The challenge here is to store the data locally in a secure way so that the data cant be deleted by the user intentionally or accidentally.

How can I achieve that ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Try the localStorage API. http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/ It's implemented a few modern browsers.

EDIT: In most browsers, clearing cookies clears localStorage.

Comment: Thanks @Neil, but I think that will be deleted when the user clears the cookies intentionally or unintentionally...